# Why is there an error saying "symbol not found" when I clearly defined the Clock instances above?

Tags: java, constructor, default-constructor

```
public class TestClock {

    public static void main(String[] args){
      /*(1)declare int variables hA, mA, hB, mB, hC, mC
       */
        int hA;
        int mA;
        int hB;
        int mB;
        int hC;
        int mC;

      /*(2)declare String variables milA, milB, milC, civA, civB, civC
       */
        String milA;
        String milB;
        String milC;
        String civA;
        String civB;
        String civC;

      /*(3)declare Clock variables clockA, clockB, clockC */
        Clock clockA;
        Clock clockB;
        Clock clockC;

      /*(4)construct clockA using default constructor */
        clockA = new Clock();

      /*(5)construct clockB using alternate constructor
       *    for military time 2400
       */
        clockB = new Clock();

      /*(6)construct clockC using alternate constructor
       *    with hours=11 and minutes=45
       */
        clockC = new Clock();

      /*(7)print clockA, clockB, clockC on separate lines
       */
        System.out.println(clockA());
        System.out.println(clockB());
        System.out.println(clockC());
```

EDIT: further instructions...

```
/*(8)assign hours and minutes to hA,mA, hB,mB, hC,mC
   *   using the hours() and minutes() methods
   *   for clockA, clockB, and clockC respectively
   */
    hA = clockA(hours);
    mA = clockA(minutes);
    hB = clockB(hours);
    mB = clockB(minutes);
    hC = clockC(hours);
    mC = clockC(minutes);

  /*(9)assign militaryTime and civilianTime to milA, civA,
   *    milB, civB, milC, civC for clockA,clockB,clockC resp
   *   using the appropriate methods
   */
```

This program (TestClock) is made to test all the methods from the program Clock (made separately, see code below). The comments are the instructions for what we have to do. So why, for the print statements, does it say clockA, clockB, and clockC not found when I clearly have them defined above as new Clocks?

Here is the separate Clock program:

```
public class Clock {
/* instance field:  
 *   totalMinutes is always between 1 and 24*60 
 */

private int totalMinutes;   

/** default constructor sets the clock to represent 12:01 a.m.
 */
public  Clock(){
  totalMinutes = 1;  
}           //end default constructor

/** alternate contructor sets clock to represent time in military
 *  parameter hours - number of hours since midnight previous day
 *  parameter minutes - number of minutes since last hour changed
 *  e.g.  14:03 military is equivalent to 2:03 p.m. civilian
 *  preconditions:  0<=hours<=24, 0<=minutes<=59,
 *                  0<hours*60 + minutes<=24*60
 */
 public Clock(int hours, int minutes){
    totalMinutes = hours*60 + minutes;
    String errMsg = null;
    if ( minutes < 0 || minutes > 59){
        errMsg = "\nminutes="+minutes+" not between 0 and 59";
    } else if ( hours < 0 || hours > 24){
        errMsg = "\nhours="+hours + " not between 0 and 24";
    }  else if (totalMinutes < 1 || totalMinutes>60*24 ) {
        errMsg = "\ntotalMinutes not between 1 and 24*60";
    }
    if (errMsg != null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(errMsg);
    }
}              //end alternate constructor

/** returns the number of hours in this Clock's time
*/
public int hours(){
 int hrs = totalMinutes / 60;
 return hrs;
}

/** returns the number of minutes since the last hour change
*/
public int minutes(){
 int min = totalMinutes % 60;
 return min;
}

/** returns a printable version of the time in Military context
*/
public String militaryTime(){
 String mTime = "",hStr="",mStr="";
 int hours = totalMinutes / 60;
 int minutes = totalMinutes % 60;
 if (hours<10){
     hStr = "0"+hours;
 } else {
     hStr = "" + hours;
 }
 if (minutes<10){
     mStr = "0"+minutes;
 } else {
     mStr = "" + minutes;
 }     
 mTime = hStr + "" + mStr;
 return mTime;
}
/** returns a printable version of the time in Civilian context
*/
public String civilianTime(){
 String cTime = "", mStr="", suffix="";
 int hours = totalMinutes / 60;
 int minutes = totalMinutes % 60;
 if ( totalMinutes == 12*60 ){  
     cTime = "12:00 noon";
 }else if ( totalMinutes == 24*60) 
     cTime = "12:00 midnight";
 else {  //neither noon nor midnight
    if (minutes < 10) {
        mStr = "0" + minutes;
    } else {
        mStr = "" + minutes;
    }    
    if (totalMinutes > 12*60){
         hours = hours - 12;
         suffix = " p.m.";
    } else {
        suffix = " a.m.";
    }
    cTime = hours + ":" + mStr + suffix;
 }       //end neithernoon nor midnight

  return cTime;
 }

}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(clockA);` Not `System.out.println(clockA());`

Comment: Kindly provide that stacktrace. What is the exact error that you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like `System.out.println(clockA());` i.e `clockA()`.

Change it to    `System.out.println(clockA);`. Override `toString()` in Clock class.

> Why is there an error saying “symbol not found” when I clearly defined the Clock instances above?

Above error generally comes when the Class type is not recognized. So `import your class Clock`.

Comment: In the this case, the error is probably referring to the symbol `clockX` which is not a method that be found.

Comment: Yes it looks like that.

Comment: Thank you I sort of knew that just didn't think of it...

Comment: And how would I do the "EDIT" further instructions in the question above? I'm not quite sure what it means by "assign"

Answer (score 0):

```
/*(7)print clockA, clockB, clockC on separate lines
*/
System.out.println(clockA());
System.out.println(clockB());
System.out.println(clockC());
```

you are using `clockC()` since you added `()` it refer to a method.

if you want to print your variable, use :

```
/*(7)print clockA, clockB, clockC on separate lines
*/
System.out.println(clockA);
System.out.println(clockB);
System.out.println(clockC);
```

Answer (score 0):

The lines such as: 
 System.out.println(clockA());
 hA = clockA(hours);
are wrong. clockA is an object and it is not a function to be called so don't use clockA().Similarly,clockA(hours) is wrong.clockA is not a method to be invoked with passing of argument i.e. "hours". Instead do proper invoking of methods through the object of class as :

#### int hA= clockA.hours();

and pass the parameters while creation of different objects of class Clock.
The parameterized constructor will be called as below:

#### clockA=new Clock(hours,minutes);

The non-parameterized constructor will be called as below:

#### clockA=new Clock();

Similarly pass different parameters for different objects created.